# Microsoft Word 2010 page numbering/header and footer

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

In Microsoft Word 2010, I am trying to number a multi-page document which has different annexes and page numbers. Is there a way I can treat each page individually, and number each page differently without it affecting the numbering of the other pages? I've been trying to figure this out, but nothing so far.

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft, you can acheive this by following [these](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Number-pages-differently-in-different-sections-1ba9047e-4534-460f-8003-12a81bb527f3?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) instructions:

> You can use different numbering formats in different parts of your
>   document.
>
> For example, maybe you want i, ii, iii numbering for the table of
>   contents and introduction, and you want 1, 2, 3 numbering for the rest
>   of the document, and then no page numbers for the index.
>
> IMPORTANT:  To use different numbering in different sections of your
>   document, you need to make sure that the sections are not linked.
>
> Click at the beginning of the page where you want to start, stop, or
>   change the header, footer, or page numbering.
>
> On the Page Layout tab, in the Page Setup group, click Breaks.
>
> page setup group
>
> Under Section Breaks, click Next Page.
>
> On the page that follows the section break, double-click in the header
>   area or the footer area (near the top of the page or near the bottom
>   of the page).
>
> This opens the Design tab under Header & Footer Tools.
>
> On the Design tab, in the Navigation group, click Link to Previous to
>   turn it off.
>
> IMPORTANT:  If your page number is in the header, be sure that you
>   turn off linking for headers. If your page number is in the footer, be
>   sure that you turn off linking for footers. Headers and footers are
>   linked or unlinked separately.
>
> Follow the instructions for adding page numbers or for adding a header
>   and footer with a page number.
>
> NOTE:  Choose an alert and enter text here. You may also set it's
>   AlertPosition property.
>
> To choose a numbering format or the starting number, click Page Number
>   in the Header & Footer group, click Format Page Numbers, click the
>   format that you want and the Start at number that you want to use, and
>   then click OK.
>
> To return to the body of your document, click Close Header and Footer
>   on the Design tab (under Header & Footer Tools).

Answer (score 0):

### Word really does not know what a Page is.

It really paginates as a part of the process of printing and in relation to the print driver being used by the user. You could put a page break between each page and type the number on it. This is a huge mess for editing. You might as well be using a typewriter!

You can change the numbering format and starting number in different Word sections. Here is my writing on [Page Numbers in Word](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#PageNumbers).

I think the following would help you meet your goals:

- [Word Doesn't Know What a Page Is](https://wordmvp.com/Mac/PagesInWord.html) by Daiya Mitchell, Word MVP
- [Using the StyleRef Field](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#STYLEREF) *(my page)*
- [Numbering Front Matter](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/FrontMatterRibbon.htm) by Suzanne Barnhill, Word MVP