# Page numbering - numbers are all the same number in section 3 it should be sequential

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

i have a 24 Page WORD document that i want to number, i have different sections and i want to start numbering at section '2', section 2 is only one page so numbering it is not a problem, the problem is when i'm numbering the same section! section 3 is more than 10 pages and i can't get the numbers to be continuous, the entire section is numbered with exactly the same number! i have seen [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1144408/microsoft-word-2010-page-numbering-header-and-footer)
and also [this](https://superuser.com/questions/741549/how-do-i-set-up-continuous-paging-in-word-across-different-sections) but no luck. connection to earlier sections is turned off and the first page is different.
please any help would be great because i have to finish the document very soon
thx

Comment: Post a sample document. Spelling: In English oneself is expressed as `I` and not `i`.

Comment: You say the page number stays the same through an entire section, are you sure you are not typing a number instead of inserting a `SectionPages` field?

Comment: @harrymc, thanks for the lesson in the English language. Next time oneself posts a question here, oneself will surely pay more attention to oneself grammar because without a perfectly written sentence you obviously can't understand anything.

Comment: Happy to have been of service to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

### You need to insert PAGE fields, not type the number.

Here is my writing on [page numbering in Word](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#PageNumbers). You can insert a PAGE field in Windows versions of Word by pressing **Alt+Shift+P**.

Here is a link to the best page on setting up numbering in different sections.
[Numbering Front Matter](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/FrontMatterRibbon.htm) by Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill.

There is also a SECTION field and a SECTIONPAGES field. Here is [my list of the different fields that can be used](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#Pagination).

> Word has four fields that work for page numbers. These are {PAGE},
> {NUMPAGES}, {SECTIONPAGES}, and {DOCPROPERTY PAGES}. These can be used
> in Calculation and IF fields and are normally used in headers and
> footers. They are classified as Document Information fields.
>
> **PAGE field**
>
> *The simplest way to insert a PAGE field is Alt+Shift+P.* They can be
> inserted through Word's interface as well. These methods insert a {
> PAGE } field in the Page Number Character Style. If you type the word
> "Page" without quotation marks, select it, and press Ctrl+F9, then F9,
> you will create the same field not in any particular style.
>
> In its simplest form this will display the page number, numbered from
> the beginning of the document. You can format any of the page number
> to display in Roman numerals (upper- or lower-case), Arabic numerals,
> or as text. More on that later. You can restart the page numbering
> anywhere you want; doing so will insert a new Section if you are not
> already at the start of a new Section.
>
> The PAGE field updates instantly upon a change in pagination of the
> document.
>
> **NUMPAGES field**
>
> The NUMPAGES field reports the total number of pages in the document.
> Unlike the PAGE field, it is not possible to restart the numbering of
> the NUMPAGES field. The NUMPAGES field, like the PAGE field updates
> upon any change in pagination.
>
> **SECTION field**
>
> The SECTION field reports the number of the Section in which it is
> located. If placed in a header or footer it shows the section in which
> the page starts. (There can be more than one section on a page.)
>
> **SECTIONPAGES field** *(there is no SECTIONPAGE field)*
>
> The SECTIONPAGES field reports the total number of pages in a Word
> Section. A document must have at least one Section and can have many.
> It is often used to number Appendices in a document. There is no
> SECTIONPAGE field that would correspond to the PAGE field. See Page
> Numbering on Greg Maxey's site for a workaround that allows the user
> to have both the Section pages numbers and of the Document page
> numbers in the same spot. This field also updates instantly. You can
> vote on UserVoice for Microsoft to add such a SECTIONPAGE field.
>
> **DOCPROPERTY PAGES field**
>
> Technically, this is a use of the DOCPROPERTY field with the Pages
> argument. In most cases it will report the same number as the NUMPAGES
> field but it has been used as a workaround for instances when the
> NUMPAGES field does not update properly and if there is a Cover Page
> in a Word 2010-2013(365) document, this will include the Cover Page in
> the numbering while the NUMPAGES field will not. When there is a Cover
> Page the number reported by NUMPAGES and the document property may be
> different.
>
> The NUMPAGES field will update more frequently than the DOCPROPERTY
> field. Its updating in virtually instant while the DOCPROPERTY field
> follows other rules.

Above quoted, without hyperlinks, from [my material on pagination fields](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#Pagination).